# Check when any user is connected slack API

Tags: symfony, slack-api, ngrok

I want to know when any user is connected to my slack workspace. I know that with `presence_change` event I can get that info, but passing the user ID.

What I want to achieve is to send an event to my app (right now using ngrok) when any user is connected (eg. it status changes from disconnected to connected)

EDIT:

Finally I discovered that if you listen that event without user_id, it will returns the ID of the user that triggered that event. If this help anyone.

Comment: So you need a webhook that will trigger an action on your application?

Answer (score 0):

I know you already answered you own question and it's kinda old now, but it could help others.

Here is what could be done:

- create a slack app
- enable event subscriptions for this app in order to call your application webhook each time the 'presence change' event happens
- in you application code, call slack api to get more details about the user that triggered this event

I detailed how to do these steps in this blog post for a very similar use case, but for another slack event (bot events), if needed: https://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/en/replace-erp-by-slack-bot-with-dialogflow-and-symfony/

Comment: Yes. It is another solution. I've tried it but for my use case I finally decided to create a Symfony command with an event listener (Botman package).
Thanks for your answer :)